# Facebook Like button not working in IE8 or IE9

Tags: facebook-like

I've been banging my head against this for over a day now and am finally posting a question, since I can't figure it out nor can find any information out there from people who are experiencing the same issue.

These Like buttons work fine in Chrome, Firefox, IE7, but NOT in IE8 nor IE9.

Do any of you Facebook gurus have any idea what may be going on here?  The buttons work fine in production.

But for this page, in IE8 & IE9, if you're not logged in to Facebook, you get a popup prompting you to log in.  After successful login, you're forwarded to (referencing you're url, instead of mine):
[http://www.facebook.com/connect/connect_to_external_page_widget_loggedin.php?social_plugin=like&external_page_url=http%3A%2F%2Fwebhooks.digitas.com%2Flike.html#*=*](http://www.facebook.com/connect/connect_to_external_page_widget_loggedin.php?social_plugin=like&external_page_url=http://webhooks.digitas.com/like.html#_=_)

If you're already logged in, you go straight to this url.  As you can see, the page never finishes whatever it's supposed to do.

I just don't understand how a button can work in production, but not in this test page.....

My test page contains 3 like buttons, taken directly from the like button code generator [page](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/).

```
<!doctype html> 
<html xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>(function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

    <div class="fb-like" data-href="http://webhooks.digitas.com/like.html" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="200" data-show-faces="false"></div>

    <fb:like href="http://webhooks.digitas.com/like.html" send="false" layout="button_count" width="200" show_faces="false"></fb:like>

    <iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwebhooks.digitas.com%2Flike.html&amp;send=false&amp;layout=button_count&amp;width=200&amp;show_faces=false&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font&amp;height=21" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:200px; height:21px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

The test page is located at http://webhooks.digitas.com/like.html

I also created another [page](http://webhooks.digitas.com/like2.html) using an alternate method of loading the Facebook JS SDK that currently works on our production site:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({ appId: '168861203149296', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true });
    };

    (function() {
        var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
        e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
    } ());

</script>
```

Comment: It's working just fine for me on IE9.

Comment: hmm.  at least that's encouraging.

Comment: Works just fine for me in IE9 as well.

Answer (score 0):

There's two things you will need to do to help things out.

1) In the FB.init you should set the ChannelUrl. 
2) In the headers your webserver sends out, you must specify a P3P header.  See here for how to implement:  http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheImportanceOfP3PAndACompactPrivacyPolicy.aspx